# Elasticsearch similar documents in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, morelikethis

I'm doing a website (an auction website) using java. I have one page to show the product in auction and I want to show 10 similar products.

To perform the search I'm using elasticsearch (by using the elasticsearch java implementation dadoonet).

One requirement I have is to show only the 10 similar documents that has date > now.

I say the elasticsearch documentation and I found the query "More like this" but first I'm not getting this to work using:

```
new MoreLikeThisRequest("auction").searchSize(size).id(productId + "").fields(new String[] { "name", "description", "brand" }).type("string");
```

Because is always showing the error:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.engine.DocumentMissingException: [_na][_na] [string][2]: document missing
```

And I'm not find the way to filter the date.

Someone can point me on the right way to do this?

thks

Comment: How did you define your document's schema?

Comment: My mapping query is (is not complete):
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/auction" -d'
{"mappings": {
     "product": {  
      "_source" : {"enabled" : true},
        "properties": {
           "name": {     
      "type": "multi_field",
      "fields": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
      "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
                    }
           (...)

Comment: Type is "product" not "string".

Comment: I did change already to product and use also the Jettro Coenradie suggestion and the error is gone but no results are returned. I don't know why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best bet would be that you have the wrong id and I also see that you are missing the type. To use more like this, you have to provide the document to use. This is defined by the combination of index,type and id. If you do not specify the document right, elasticsearch cannot find the document and that is most probably why you get the document missing message.

In java I would do something like this:

```
FilteredQueryBuilder queryBuilder = 
        new FilteredQueryBuilder(
                QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),
                FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("datefield").lte("now")
        );
SearchSourceBuilder query = SearchSourceBuilder.searchSource().query(queryBuilder);

client.prepareMoreLikeThis("index","type","id")
    .setField("field1","field2")
    .setSearchSource(query)
    .execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: So I change what I did for what you say using as index "auction" as type "product" and the error is gone but nothing is return. Another thing is I'm not seeing the way to exclude results with date < now

Comment: I changed my answer, now the code contains example to add a query with a filter to filter on all document before now. The fact that you do not get back any results is hard more me to explain. Than I should have a good example with some data as well.

Comment: The problem that I'm think it will be is the way I did the mapping (in the comment of the question)... maybe is not the way to do for more like this..

Answer (score 0):

So after strugling a little bit I found someone with the same problem. So his suggestion was to set the min_term_freq to 1.

So the code now looks like this:

```
FilteredQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new FilteredQueryBuilder(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(), FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("finish_date").lt("now"));
        SearchSourceBuilder query = SearchSourceBuilder.searchSource().query(queryBuilder);
        SearchResponse response = esClient.prepareMoreLikeThis("auction", "product", productId + "").setField("name.name", "description", "brand").setPercentTermsToMatch(0.3f)
                .setMinTermFreq(1).setSearchSource(query).execute().actionGet();
```

But I dont know what this MinTermFreq does and if the value 1 is the right value. Someone know what is this field?

Thks for all the help!

Once again, Thank you for all the help and sorry for all the trouble!